# How to use sdpm() or dpm()?

Tags: 7, debugging

Almost everywhere I search I find the following example for using `dpm()` or `sdpm()` with the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and the [Search Krumo](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_krumo) modules:

> Paste the following code in your theme's template.php file, save, and clear cache.
>
> ```
> function foo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
>   if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
>     sdpm($form);
>   }
> }
> ```

This is working fine.

But how can I see the other components, like Menu and its components or any block?

I tried following for menu but it is not working.

```
function mymodule_menu_link_alter(&$item, $menu) {
   sdpm($menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_menu_link_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7.x) accepts only one argument in Drupal 7. That's why your code isn't working.

Try the following:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  if ($item['menu_name'] == 'YOUR_MENU') {
    dpm($item);
  }
}
```

I have wrapped it in an if check, since otherwise it would run `dpm` for all menu links on a page and depending on the amount of links it may cause memory overflow or timeout.

Comment: Something looks wrong, it is not working. even I did check by removing if statement. I have enabled two menu for check i.e. main-menu and user-menu. any suggestion?

Comment: Did you clear the caches? is the module enabled?

Comment: Yes, I did clear cache every time.

Comment: I have made a correction on the if statement, `$item` is an array not an object. But it doesn't solve your problem that the hook isn't called.

Comment: `dpm()` and the likes are useful when you know exactly what you're looking for. If you want to be able to browse all variables that are available at a certain point in the code, I recommend using a debugger (like Xdebug) combined with a good IDE (like PhpStorm). Personally, I haven't touched Devel and Krumo since I got the hang of Xdebug.

Comment: XDebug (+ PHPStorm) are unbeatable for debugging.

Comment: I will try Xdebug+PHPStorm. Thanks. @ЕлинЙ. I have one question, if I am dealing with Main menu, what am I suppose to place at `menu_name` and `YOUR_MENU`? Here I have only one thing main-menu?

Comment: `main-menu` is the machine name of the main menu

Comment: if I place this code   `if ($item['menu_name'] == 'main-menu') {dpm($item);}`  also it is not working.